# Parsing Org-Mode Timelog Data

Tags: plotting, dataset

Suppose we have in `~/time-data/time-data.org` the following data:

```
* Parent1
:LOGBOOK:
CLOCK: [2019-07-09 Tue 00:00]--[2019-07-09 Tue 00:20] =>  0:20
:END:
** Child1
:LOGBOOK:
CLOCK: [2019-07-10 Wed 00:02]--[2019-07-10 Wed 00:40] =>  0:38
:END:
** Child2
:LOGBOOK:
CLOCK: [2019-07-11 Thu 00:02]--[2019-07-11 Thu 06:40] =>  0:38
:END:
```

We then can use [atheriel/org-clock-csv](https://github.com/atheriel/org-clock-csv) to to pull this data via

```
(org-clock-csv-to-file "~/time-data/time-data.csv" '("~/time-data/time-data.org"))
```

which populates `time-data.csv` with

```
task,parents,category,start,end,effort,ishabit,tags
Parent1,,,2019-07-09 00:00,2019-07-09 00:20,,,
Child1,Parent1,,2019-07-10 00:02,2019-07-10 00:40,,,
Child2,Parent1,,2019-07-11 00:02,2019-07-11 06:40,,,
```

so that in Mathematica we can run:

> [image]

**Question:** How do we get a `DateListPlot` out of this that shows, i.e., hours spent per day?

---

**EDIT:** I fed everyone's answers through my actual data (which spans several months) and [published them here](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/george.w.singer/Published/time-data). I get lots of errors and (mostly) unparsable graphs. I think these answers are getting me closer to something usable though!

Comment: If you do `ds = SemanticImport["f.csv", HeaderLines->1]`, then `DateListPlot[ds[All, "start"]` that will get you somewhere. Also have a look at `TimelinePlot` - you could generate intervals using the start and ends. (And hello, fellow emacser)

Comment: There is [Gantt-chart making tool for org-mode in emacs](https://orgmode.org/worg/org-tutorials/org-taskjuggler.html), but I never made it work. So, I did/do similar imports and timeline plots.

Comment: Can you add your "time-data.csv" file?

Comment: M.R.: See above.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If Mathematica was perfect, `DateHistogram[..., "Day", "Hour"]` would work, making what you want a one-liner. I believe that a `DateInterval` function might be coming in the next version (12.1) which would presumably work with `DateHistogram` and `TimelinePlot`.

All that aside, let's see how to chart a temporal histogram across all of your tasks. First, let's import your dataset:

```
csv = "task,parents,category,start,end,effort,ishabit,tags
      Parent1,,,2019-07-07 00:00,2019-07-07 00:20,,,
      Child1,Parent1,,2019-07-8 00:02,2019-07-8 00:40,,,
      Child2,Parent1,,2019-07-9 00:02,2019-07-9 06:40,,,
      Parent2,,,2019-07-08 00:00,2019-07-08 00:20,,,
      Child21,Parent2,,2019-07-9 00:02,2019-07-9 00:40,,,
      Child22,Parent2,,2019-07-10 00:02,2019-07-10 06:40,,,
      Parent3,,,2019-07-09 00:00,2019-07-09 00:20,,,
      Child31,Parent3,,2019-07-10 00:02,2019-07-10 00:40,,,
      Child32,Parent3,,2019-07-11 00:02,2019-07-11 06:40,,,";
ds = ImportString[csv, {"CSV", "Dataset"}, HeaderLines -> 1];
```

[image]

Now with a single `GroupBy[]` command, we change the raw data into the form we need:

```
data = GroupBy[ds[All, <|"p" -> If[#parents == "", #task, #parents], 
     "d" -> (DateObject /@ {#"start", #"end"})|> &], First -> Last, 
     Map[{CurrentDate[#[[1]], "Hour"], DateDifference[#[[1]], #[[2]], "Hour"]} &]]
```

[image]

and then visualize it by simply calling:

```
Row @ {DateListPlot[data, Filling -> Axis, ImageSize -> Medium, PlotLegends -> None],
StackedDateListPlot[data, PlotTheme -> "Detailed", ImageSize -> Medium]}
```

[image]

Another (non-dataset based) way to do this is as follows:

```
ds = ImportString[csv, "CSV"];dates = Map[DateObject, ds[[2 ;;, {4, 5}]], {-1}];
dr = Flatten[DateRange[##, "Minute"] & @@@ dates];
DateHistogram[dr, "Day", DateReduction -> "Week", FrameLabel -> {None, "Minutes"}, Frame -> True, 
 LabelingFunction -> (Column@{Quantity[#/60., "Hours"], Quantity[#, "Seconds"]} &)]
```

[image]

Or we can discretize by "Hours":

```
dr = DeleteDuplicates[DateObject[#, "Hour"] & /@ Flatten[DateRange[##, "Hours"] & @@@ dates]];
DateHistogram[dr, "Day", DateReduction -> "Week", FrameLabel -> {None, "Hours"}, Frame -> True]
```

[image]

Yet another way to analyze it (with a different coding style to boot) is to read it as a graph and plot a weighted tree-map. To further break your data down by parent task, try this:

```
edges = Normal[(Reverse /@ Rule @@@ ds[[2 ;;, {1, 2}]]) /. "" -> "Root"];
TreePlot[edges, Top, "Root", VertexLabels -> "Name", DirectedEdges -> True]
```

[image]

```
taskParent[t_] := With[{parent = FirstCase[edges, Verbatim[Rule][p_, t] :> p]}, If[parent == "Root", t, parent]];
dr = DateRange[##, "Minute"] & @@@ dates;
groups = Flatten /@ GroupBy[Thread[{taskParent /@ ds[[2 ;;, 1]], dr}], First -> Last];
DateHistogram[Values[groups], "Day", ChartLayout -> "Stacked", ChartLegends -> Keys[groups], DateReduction -> "Week", FrameLabel -> {None, "Hours"}, PlotTheme -> "Marketing"]
```

[image]

Comment: Does this fit your needs?

Comment: M.R.: Thanks for your answer! See https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/george.w.singer/Published/time-data

I fed your functions into my actual dataset (which spans several months) and got a bunch of errors/unparsable graphs.

Comment: Can we wrap all of these categories into one, as a simplifying assumption? (i.e.: don't split up the time data into different categories, but instead just plot hours logged over time).

Comment: M.R.: I was able to build on your answer to get a simpler data/graph set for my purposes. Thanks!!

Answer (score 4):

You may use the `"Dataset"` and `"HeaderLines"` [`Import`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Import.html) options for [`"CSV"`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/format/CSV.html) along with [`Dataset`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Dataset.html) and [`Query`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Query.html).

Using a slightly modified `csv` from @M.R.

```
csv = "task,parents,category,start,end,effort,ishabit,tags
    Parent1,,,2019-07-07 00:00,2019-07-07 00:20,,,
    Child1,Parent1,,2019-07-8 00:02,2019-07-8 00:40,,,
    Child2,Parent1,,2019-07-9 00:02,2019-07-9 06:40,,,
    Parent2,,,2019-07-08 00:00,2019-07-08 00:20,,,
    Child21,Parent2,,2019-07-9 00:02,2019-07-9 00:40,,,
    Child22,Parent2,,2019-07-10 00:02,2019-07-10 06:40,,,
    Parent3,,,2019-07-09 00:00,2019-07-09 00:20,,,
    Child31,Parent3,,2019-07-10 00:02,2019-07-10 00:40,,,
    Child32,Parent3,,2019-07-11 00:02,2019-07-11 06:40,,,";
```

`Import` (using `ImportString` but its the exact same options for `Import`) as a `Dataset` with

```
ds = ImportString[csv, {"CSV", "Dataset"}, "HeaderLines" -> 1]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

Convert `"start"` and `"end"` to [`DateObject`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DateObject.html)s and fill in `"parents"` for parent task to make grouping easier.

```
ds =
 Query[All, <|#, "parents" -> If[#parents == "", #task, #parents]|> &]@
  Query[All, Thread[{"start", "end"} -> DateObject]]@ds
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

[`GroupBy`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GroupBy.html) `"parents"` then the [`CurrentDate`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CurrentDate.html) `"Day"` of `"start"`, calculate the [`DateDifference`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DateDifference.html) in `"Hour"`s between `"start"` and `"end"`, [`Total`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Total.html) the hours per start day.

```
dsHours =
 ds[
  GroupBy[{#parents &, CurrentDate[#start, "Day"] &}] /* KeySort,
  All,
  Total,
  DateDifference[#start, #end, "Hour"] &
  ]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

Then [`DateListPlot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DateListPlot.html).

```
DateListPlot[dsHours, Filling -> Axis]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

or [`DateHistogram`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DateHistogram.html)

```
DateHistogram[
 dsHours[All, {Keys, Values} /* Apply[WeightedData]], "Day",
 ChartLegends -> Automatic
 ]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 4):

```
csv = "task,parents,category,start,end,effort,ishabit,tags
      Parent1,,,2019-07-07 00:00,2019-07-07 00:20,,,
      Child1,Parent1,,2019-07-8 00:02,2019-07-8 00:40,,,
      Child2,Parent1,,2019-07-9 00:02,2019-07-9 06:40,,,
      Parent2,,,2019-07-08 00:00,2019-07-08 00:20,,,
      Child21,Parent2,,2019-07-9 00:02,2019-07-9 00:40,,,
      Child22,Parent2,,2019-07-10 00:02,2019-07-10 06:40,,,
      Parent3,,,2019-07-09 00:00,2019-07-09 00:20,,,
      Child31,Parent3,,2019-07-10 00:02,2019-07-10 00:40,,,
      Child32,Parent3,,2019-07-11 00:02,2019-07-11 06:40,,,";

dt = ImportString[csv, "CSV", "HeaderLines" -> 1] /. {a_, "", b__} :> {a, a, b};

dt2 = Values @ GroupBy[dt, #[[2]] &, 
   Labeled[Interval[DateObject[#, "Minute"] & /@ {#, #2}], #3, Above] & @@@ 
     #[[All, {4, 5, 1}]] &];

tlp = TimelinePlot[dt2, 
  PlotStyle -> Thread[Directive[{Red, Green, Blue}, CapForm["Round"], Thickness[.015]]], 
  AxesOrigin -> Bottom, ImageSize -> 800, AspectRatio -> 1/3]
```

[image]

```
edges = DirectedEdge @@@ DeleteCases[dt[[All, {2, 1}]], {a_, a_}];

vertices = VertexList[edges];

vcoords = Association @ 
   Cases[tlp[[1]], Text[v_, Offset[o_, vc_], ___] :> v[[1]] -> vc, All];

grph = Show @ Graph[vertices, edges, VertexShapeFunction -> None, 
    EdgeShapeFunction -> ({Arrowheads[{{.02, .8}}], 
        Arrow@GraphElementData[{"CurvedArc", "Curvature" -> -.00001}][##]} &), 
    VertexCoordinates -> (vcoords /@ vertices), AspectRatio -> 1/3];

Show[ tlp, Prolog -> grph[[1]]]
```

[image]